# Make JSDoc comment for function which takes another function as parameter

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Imagine a function which accepts an "onUpdate" function as a parameter:

```
 /**
 * @param {function} onUpdate
 * @returns {null}
 */
static async init(onUpdate) {
    ...
    onUpdate(true);
};
```

onUpdate takes a boolean as an argument.
**I want to add that arguments to** `@param {function} onUpdate`.

Is there a way?

Some magnificent devs managed to do it on these addEventListener functions:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in screenshot you see typescript hint. But you can do something like [this](https://jsdoc.app/tags-callback.html):

```
/**
 * This callback is displayed as a global member.
 * @callback someCallback
 * @param {number} param1
 * @param {number} param2
 * @returns {number}
 */

/**
 * 
 * @param {someCallback} cb 
 */

function someFunction(cb) {

}
```

And see this [hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8piy4.png)

Comment: Thank you, I like your explanation. I'm glad someone took the time to answer me xD

Answer (score 0):

If you know the types ahead of time you can destructure it at the definition inline allowing for more complex parameters typing on your callback, for example arrays, objects etc.

```
/**
 * @callback myCallback
 * @param { { param1: number, param2: string } } - Some human friendly explanation
 *
 *
 * @returns {void}
 */

/**
 *
 * @param {myCallback} cb - The function does some cool stuff
 * @param {string} somethingElse - can still define more params for fn
 * @param {number} anotherThng - the same way as before
 *
 *
 * @returns { void } - can be any return you want to type out
 */
```